# Copy result of a region operation to kill ring

Tags: emacs

I have the following code in Emacs that removes line breaks in a highlighted region:

```
(defun remove-newlines-in-region ()
  "Removes all newlines in the region."
  (interactive)
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t) (replace-match "" nil t))))
```

I would to expand this function to also automatically **copy** (not kill) the result to the kill ring. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```el
(kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max))
```

Comment: Hmm I tried adding that line to the end of my function above, but it copied the entire buffer. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I assume you put it outside of the `save-restriction`. It needs to be inside: `point-min` and `point-max` are affected by the narrowing (something which you have already utilised in the case of the former).

Comment: That made it. Thanks! I will update the OP to make the question easier to search for.